# Angular 4 the error 'Type 'TestHostComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.' prevent UT running

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, angular-directive

I met error `Type 'TestHostComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.`, when I ran the test with `ng test` command, after including 'TestHostComponent' in UT to test a directive.

This is the `TestHostComponent`:

```
@Component({
 template: `<div someAttr></div>`
})
export class TestHostComponent {}
```

Here's part of testing code:

```
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
 let de: DebugElement;
 let comp: Component;

 beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [SomeDirective, TestHostComponent]
  })
  .createComponent(TestHostComponent);

 fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(SomeDirective));
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

 it('should be defined', () => {
   expect(de).toBeDefined();
 });
```

***Env:***

```
angular: 4.4.6

@angular/cli: 1.4.9
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can you paste your `TestHostComponent` file? or declaration? have you got `@Component` decorator inside?

Comment: @LucaTaccagni, pasted the `TestHostComponent` file for your reference, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague helped me to find out the solution at last.

It turned out I broke the tslint rules, and then it prevents UT from running.
The `Component` type of declearation `let comp: Component;` should changed to `TestHostComponent`.

Hope it will help others.